# tracking calls to a PHP WebService for each user/IP

Tags: php, web-services, security, get, ddos

Basicaly, I have an `PHP` webservice which will be available from:

- website
- mobile phone clients - (android/iphone)

Data is retreived in `JSON` format. Request is sent using `GET` method over `HTTPS` protocol. Data in database is kept in `mongo` database.

*Here comes my main questions:*

1. I want to get the statistics for each `user` - how many calls he is doing per-minute/hour - how to save this data? Will it be okay to save everything into `mongo` database? (1 day statistics = 43 millions rows) Is there a solution maybe which will keep data only for X days and then auto-trunc everything automatically?
2. I also want to get statistics for each `IP` - how many calls were made from it per-minute/hour/day - how to save this data? Will it be okay to save everything into `mongo` database? Will it not become too large?
3. Is it **always** possible to see an `IP` of an user who is making a call to a webservice? what about `IPv6`?

These 3 questions are the most interesting to me currently. I am planning on letting users use basic services without the need of loggin-in! My main concern is the database/file system performance.

**Next comes the description about - what measures I am planning to use. How did I come to this solution and why these 3 questions above are essential. Feel free to ignore the text below if you are not interested in details :)**

I want to protect my webservice against crawling I.e. somebody can pass parameters (which are not hard to guess) to get entire data off my databse :)

Here is an usage example: `https://mydomain/api.php?action=map&long=1.23&lat=2.45`

As you can see - I am already using a secure `https` protocol, in order to prevent accidental catching entire `GET` request. It also protects agains 'man in the middle' attacks. However, it doesn't stop attackers from getting into website and going through `JS` `AJAX` calls to get an actual request structure. Or decompiling entire android's `.APK` file.

After reading a lot of questions through out the internet - I came to the conclusion that there is no way of protecting my data entirely, but I think I have found an approach of making the life of a crawlers a lot harder!

**And I need your advice on either - if this whole thing is worth implementing and what technologies shall be used in my case (see next).**

Next comes the security measures against non-website (mobile device) use of a service for users which are not logged-in.

```
<?php
/*
Case: "App first started". User: "not logged in"
0. generate UNIQUE_APP_ID for APP when first started
1. send UNIQUE_APP_ID to server (or request new UNIQUE_APP_ID from server to write it on device)
    1.1. Verify how many UNIQUE_APP_IDs were created from this IP
        if more than X unique values in last Y minutes ->
            ban IP temporary
            ban all UNIQUE_APP_IDs created by IP during Y minutes (use delay to link them together).
            but exclude UNIQUE_APP_IDs from ban if these are not showing strange behaviour ( mainly - no calls to API)
            force affected users to log-in to continue to use the service or ask to retry later when ban wears off
        else register UNIQUE_APP_ID on server

        Note: this is a 'hard' case, as the IP might belong to some public Wi-Fi AP. Precautions:
            * temporary instead of permanent ban
            * activity check for each UNIQUE_APP_ID belonging to IP. There could be legit users who use the service from long time thus will not be affected by this check. Created Z time ago from this IP.
            * users will be not be ever banned - rather forced to log-in, where more restrictive actions will be performed individually!

Now that the application is registered and all validations are passed:

2. Case: "call to API is made". User: "not logged-in"
    2.1. get IP from which call is made
    2.2. get unique app ID of client
    2.3. verity ID against DB on server
        if not exists -> reject call
    2.4. check how many calls this particular ID did in the last X minutes
        if more than X calls -> ban only this unique ID
    2.5 check how many Ids were banned from this IP in the last X minutes. If more than Y then ban new calls for whole IP temporary
        check if all banned IDs were created from the same IP, if yes then also ban that IP, if it is different from new IP


*/
?>
```

As you can see - my whole solution is based on the idea that I can store the data about webservice and retrieve it for analysis easily.. for each single webservice call.. Or maybe each X'th call. I have no idea about - what kind of database shall be used. I was thinking that mongo might not be the best choice. Maybe `MySQL`? Keeping data safe from wrong users is one reason. Another reason is that abusal usage of database will result in a huge load on a database.(DDos?) So, i think this might be a good idea to count webservice calls.

On the other side. A bit of calculations.

If there are 1000 users working simultaniusly. Each generating 30 calls to a webservice per minute. So it's 30000 disc writes in a minute. In hour it's 60 times that i.e. 1.800.000 disc writes in an hour. If I am planning to keep statistics about daily usage then it's 24 times that i.e. in 
average there will be 43.200.000 records for tracking purposes kept on a server.

Each record contains information about: `time` + `IP` + `user unique ID`

I was also thinking about not storing any data at all. Use `redis` instead. I know that there is some kind of `counter` exists. For for each individual IP I can create a separate key and start counting calls. In this case everything will be kept in server's `RAM`. There is also an `expire date` parameter which is possible to set for each key. And for separate users I can store their IDs instead of network IP. This solution only came to my mind after I finished writing this whole essay, so let me hear your ideas about questions above.

Comment: You may want to look into https://getkong.org/